# ANGULAR - Return data in DOM from subscribe()

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to return with *ngFor component data found by subscribe() in my DOM, but nothing happens ...

What did I do wrong ?

My HTML :

```
<ion-item detail="false" *ngFor="let chat of chats">
      <ion-row class="w100">
        <ion-col [size]="3">
          <div class="container-img-screenable">
            <img class="img-screenable" [src]="getContenderImg(chat.contenderID)" alt="">
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col [size]="9">
          <div class="reposi">
            <h1 class="title">{{getContenderNameTruncated(chat.contenderID)}}</h1>
            <p class="text">{{getLastSentence(chat.chatID)}}</p>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
```

One of the three functions in my Component.TS :

```
getLastSentence(chatID:any){
    var path = '/Chats/' + chatID + '/lastMessage';
    this.CrudService.read(path).subscribe((lastSentence:any) => {
      return lastSentence
    })
}
```

Good to know : All functions return the good data, I've verified with console.log, the problem come when I want to return it ... I'm sure that is obvious but I'm newbie ...

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking...

Comment: @mwilson What do you mean ? I have a ngFor loop, and I want to return data for each record, but when I try, nothing happens and in my console.log, I have an infinite loop ... I just want return data without problem ... Sorry if I was not clear and feel free to ask me all you need to know for helping me ...

Comment: you cannot return this inside subscribe

Comment: Thank you @Talg123, what did you suggest ? I really want to improve my skills ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I see is that the function `getLastSentence` doesn't return any value. I would get rid of subscribe block and used the async pipe:

```js
<ion-item detail="false" *ngFor="let chat of chats">
      <ion-row class="w100">
        <ion-col [size]="3">
          <div class="container-img-screenable">
            <img class="img-screenable" [src]="getContenderImg(chat.contenderID)" alt="">
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col [size]="9">
          <div class="reposi">
            <h1 class="title">{{getContenderNameTruncated(chat.contenderID)}}</h1>
            <p class="text">{{getLastSentence(chat.chatID) | async | json}}</p>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
```

And your `getLastSentence` function will look like this and return `Observable`:

```js
getLastSentence(chatID:any): Observable<any> {
    var path = '/Chats/' + chatID + '/lastMessage';
    return this.CrudService.read(path);
}
```

This way you don't need to worry about unsubscribing, because the async pipe will do it for your on component destroy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I try, it's return [object Object] ...

Comment: Try to see what’s in there using {{ |json}} pipe in the template

Comment: I have this error = ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Zone'
    |     property '_zoneDelegate' -> object with constructor 'ZoneDelegate'

Comment: take a look, I updated my answer. I meant to use both `async` and   `json` pipes

Comment: I have try but it return : "null" ... (The value is not null)

Comment: Well null looks like something probable. What do you see in the Network tab of your Chrome when you perform the request?

Answer (score 1):

Change your subscribe into async/await

```
async getLastSentence(chatID: string): Promise<string> {
    const path = `/Chats/${chatID}/lastMessage`;
    return await this.CrudService.read(path).toPromise()
}
```

To be honest Id actually check if there is a response and check its value.
The thing is that you cannot return inside a subscribe, so you have few ways of doing it, this is the best tbh.

Comment: I've try but my IDE says "type unknow can not be assignable to type string", I edited the Promise, but it return [object Promise] ...

Comment: I dont know what your endpoint return... You need to know, and if it return something that is not a string just get the response and then return what you need inside it.

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
*ngFor="let chat of chats | async"
```

as for subscribing, you don't need it because async takes care of subscription and unsubscription. However if you have to use it, remember to unsubscribe otherwise you may have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that you have a variable `chats`

```
chats: Array<any>;
```

2. Then assign the result from your service call to the variable `chats`

```
getLastSentence(chatID:any){
    var path = '/Chats/' + chatID + '/lastMessage';
    this.chats = this.CrudService.read(path);
}
```

3. Then use the `async` pipe in your HTML template to access the values in the chats array.

```
<ion-item detail="false" *ngFor="let chat of chats | async">
      <ion-row class="w100">
        <ion-col [size]="3">
          <div class="container-img-screenable">
            <img class="img-screenable" [src]="getContenderImg(chat.contenderID)" alt="">
          </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col [size]="9">
          <div class="reposi">
            <h1 class="title">{{getContenderNameTruncated(chat.contenderID)}}</h1>
            <p class="text">{{getLastSentence(chat.chatID) | async | json}}</p>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
```